# Avoiding R-error "replacement has length zero" in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, missing-data

I have a dataframe like the following showing values of certain companys depending on a year:

```
#   company year value1 value2
# 1       1 2019      1     10
# 2       1 2020     11    110
# 3       1 2021    111   1110
# 4       2 2019      2     20
# 5       2 2021    222   2220
# 6       3 2019      3     30
# 7       3 2020     33    330
# 8       3 2021    333   3330
```

Values for company 2 in 2020 are missing. Now I want to sum up the values for each company in a certain year, e.g. 2020:

```
df_sum <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:3) {
  # number of the company
  df_sum[i, 1] <- i
  # sum of the company's values
  df_sum[i, 2] <- df[df$company == i & df$year == 2020, "value1"] + 
    df[df$company == i & df$year == 2020, "value2"]
}
```

R gives the output

> Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- replacement has length zero

as company 2 is missing the values for 2020 and therefore the for loop terminates.

How can I achieve that the missing values are treated like "NA + NA = NA (i.e.: df_sum[2,2] is NA)" and that the for loop doesn't terminate?

The dataframe df_sum should look like this:

```
  company | sum of values
-------------------------
1|      1 |           121
2|      2 |            NA
3|      3 |           363
```

### data

```
df <- structure(list(company = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), year = c(2019, 
2020, 2021, 2019, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2021), value1 = c(1, 11, 
111, 2, 222, 3, 33, 333), value2 = c(10, 110, 1110, 20, 2220, 
30, 330, 3330)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You've not described what you are trying to do nor your expected output, but I believe you can avoid the use of loops entirely.  In the tidyverse, something like `df %>% group_by(company) %>% summarise(across(-year, sum))` should be close to what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not describing correctly. I tried to edit my first post showing the expected output. I'm trying to use a for loop to sum up both values of each company depending on an explicit year.

Answer (score 0):

Company 2 has no observation in year 2020, so that what you want to assign to `df_sum[i, 2] <-` has length zero, this is what the error is complaining about.

You could consider a case handling inf an `if/else` clause, where we assign `NA_real` `if` there's not `any` observation.

```
df_sum <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(unique(df$company)), ncol=2) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c('company', 'sum_of_values'))  ## *

for (i in 1:3) {
  # number of the company
  df_sum[i, 1] <- i
  # sum of the company's values
  v <- with(df, company == i & year == 2020)
  if (any(v)) {
    df_sum[i, 2] <- df[v, "value1"] + df[v, "value2"]
  } else {
    df_sum[i, 2] <- NA_real_
  }
}

df_sum
#   company sum_of_values
# 1       1           121
# 2       2            NA
# 3       3           363
```

*It's better to initialize an object with it's size, when its known as in this case. The effect is, that memory is pre-allocated, and the thing, thus, much faster.

Without a `for` loop (which are rather slow in R), you could `cbind` company to the `rowSums` of the two values, subset it by 2020, and `merge` it to `unique` companies.

```
cbind(df['company'], 
      sum_of_values=rowSums(df[c('value1', 'value2')]))[df$year == 2020, ] |>
  merge(unique(df[c('company')]), all=TRUE)
#   company sum_of_values
# 1       1           121
# 2       2            NA
# 3       3           363
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think jay.sf's answer is much neater and likely a better (or more efficient) option to mine. However, I'd already written the below so thought I might chime in with my alternatives.

Option 1: To use your for loop (almost) as is, you will need to generate the missing data and populate it with NAs, for instance with a nested loop. (I also changed to sum() instead of + to sum the values)

```
df_full=data.frame(company=NULL, year=NULL, value1=NULL, value2=NULL)

#extract data
for(comp in 1:max(df$company)) { #per company
  for (yr in c(2019, 2020, 2021)){#per year
    
    #subset original dataframe by company and year
    dfsub=subset(df, company==comp & year==yr)
    
    if (sum(dfsub)==0) { #no data so output NA
        dfsub=data.frame(company=comp,
                         year=yr,
                         value1=NA,
                         value2=NA)
    } 
    
    #bind subset to output dataframe
    df_full=rbind(df_full, dfsub)
  }
}

#Now use your for loop on df_full
df_sum <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:3) {
  # number of the company
  df_sum[i, 1] <- i
  # sum of the company's values (notice change to sum() function)
  df_sum[i, 2] <- sum(df_full[df_full$company == i & df_full$year == 2020, "value1"], df_full[df_full$company == i & df_full$year == 2020, "value2"])
}
```

Option 2: Do the summing for all years at once using a similar nested loop

```
df_sum <- data.frame(Company=NULL, value=NULL)

for(comp in 1:max(df$company)) { #per company
  for (yr in c(2019, 2020, 2021)){#per year
    
    #subset original dataframe by company and year
    dfsub=subset(df, company==comp & year==yr)
    
    if (sum(dfsub)==0) { #no data so output NA
      output=data.frame(company=comp, year=yr, value=NA)
    } else { #data exists so sum it
      output=data.frame(company=comp, year=yr, value=sum(dfsub$value1, dfsub$value2))
    }
    #bind output to df_sum
    df_sum=rbind(df_sum, output)
  }
}
```

Hopefully helpful to see what's going on a little more explicitly, but there are more efficient ways to do this kind of thing